# Using the Mean Value Theorem, show that for all positive integers $n$, $n\ln(1+\frac{1}{n}) \leq 1$

Tags: calculus, inequality, rolles-theorem

I am not too familiar with Rolle's Theorem and MVT so this question is a little bit tricky for me.

I tried it by letting some $$f(x)=x\ln(1+\frac{1}{x})-1.$$
Then by MVT, in the interval $x \in [0,n]$, there exists a point $c$, $c \in ]0,n[$, such that,
$$\frac{f(n)-f(0)}{n-0} =f'(c)$$
Which simplifies to,
$$\ln(1+\frac{1}{n})=f'(c).$$
By letting $c=0$ we get
$$\ln(1+\frac{1}{n}) \leq f'(0)$$
Then $\ln(1+\frac{1}{n}) \leq \infty$
which is obviously nowhere near the desired inequality.

Comment: Call $x= \frac{1}{n}$, and prove that $\ln(1+x) \le x$.

Comment: You don't **choose** $c$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inequality you really want is
$$\ln(1+x)\le x\tag{1}$$
valid for $x>0$. Setting $x=1/n$ in ($1$) proves your given one.

To prove $(1)$, apply MVT to $f(t)=\ln(1+t)$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**
$$\ln(1+\frac{1}{n})\leq \frac{1}{n} \Rightarrow 1+\frac{1}{n} \leq e^{\frac{1}{n}}$$

We know that $e = \lim_{n\to\infty}(1+\frac{1}{n})^n$ and we know $(1+\frac{1}{n})^n$ is increasing. Hence, for each $n$, $(1+\frac{1}{n})^n \leq e$ and $1+\frac{1}{n} \leq (1+\frac{1}{n})^n$.

Answer (score 0):

$ \dfrac {\ln (1+1/n)-\ln 1}{1/n}= \ln' (t)= 1/t$,

where $1<t<1+1/n.$

Hence : $n \ln (1+1/n) =1/t \lt 1$.